# Dismiss view from view model [MODAL PAGE]

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm using swiftUI and combine, I'have some business logic in my VM. Some results have to dismiss my view.

I'v used this one in some views :

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
```

I want to something similar in my view model.

Comment: Please give more details about your problem and what you want to achieve.

Comment: You don't do the dismissal in _imperative_ way in `SwiftUI`. Instead you use a `.sheet` type view by binding it to a boolean property that will be mutated from that said view model.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You don't do the dismissal in imperative way in `SwiftUI`. Instead you use a `.sheet` view by binding it to a boolean property that will be mutated from that said view model.

### Edit:

> After answering a follow-up
>   [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59135150/pop-navigation-view-from-viewmodel/59151042),
>   I came up with a different approach. It plays nice if the dismissal is
>   actually needed to be done from inside the modally presented `View`
>   itself.

You can achieve this by implementing your custom `Publisher` which will use `.send()` method to allow you to send specific values to the subscriber (in this case, your `View`). You will use `onReceive(_:perform:)` method defined on the `View` protocol of **SwiftUI** to subscribe to the output stream of the custom `Publisher` you defined. Inside the `perform` action closure where you will have the access to the latest emitted value of your publisher, you will do the actual dismissal of your `View`.

Enough of the theory, you can look at the code, should not be very hard to follow, below:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var viewDismissalModePublisher = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
    private var shouldDismissView = false {
        didSet {
            viewDismissalModePublisher.send(shouldDismissView)
        }
    }

    func performBusinessLogic() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.shouldDismissView = true
        }
    }
}
```

And the views counterparts is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isDetailShown = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
            Button(action: {
                self.isDetailShown.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Present Detail")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isDetailShown) {
            DetailView()
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail")
        .navigationBarTitle("Detail", displayMode: .inline)
        .onAppear {
            self.viewModel.performBusinessLogic()
        }
        .onReceive(viewModel.viewDismissalModePublisher) { shouldDismiss in
            if shouldDismiss {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Old Answer:

A very simple implementation of view dismissal with respect to business logic changes in View Model would be:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")

        // the animation() modifier is optional here
        .sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.isSheetShown.animation()) { 
            Text("Sheet Presented")
        }

        // From here - for illustration purpose
        .onAppear {
            self.viewModel.perform()
        }
        // To here

    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isSheetShown = false

    func perform() {
        // this just an example. In real application, you will be responsible to
        // toggle between the states of the `Bool` property
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.isSheetShown.toggle()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                self.isSheetShown.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well @theMouk, I think this answered your question already. If that is so, you should first mark this as accepted for this will help future readers with the similar issues. And the navigation view pop should be a separate question instead.

Comment: Thanks! it worked for me (newbie).
Lots of lines to close the View from the ViewModel. I hope future versions of Swift offer a more streamlined approach.

Comment: I would also like to add that this answer is better than using `@Published` on that particular property in the view model because if you use protocols to define the view model, you'll get a compile error since you can't use wrapped properties along with protocols and your view wouldn't know that the property is a publisher if it was defined in that protocol. Using the Combine syntax without the `@Publisher` fixes it.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to make it simple then just make a @Published variable in viewModel called goBack of type Bool and change it to true whenever you want and in the view just use the .onChange modifier if that bool is true on change then run presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss().

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var goBack: Bool = false
  
  fun itWillToggleGoBack() {
    goBack.toggle()
  }
}


struct MyView {
  @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

  var body: some View {
    Text("Any kind of view")
      .onChange(of: vm.goBack) { goBack in 
         if goBack {
           self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
         }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: The disadvantage of this method is that if you use a protocol to define your view model's functionality, you'll get a compile error since protocols don't work well with wrapped properties. The view basically wouldn't know that the property has the `@Published` keyword; however using the Combine syntax fixes that since it would be clearly defined in the protocol that it's a `PassthroughSubject`

Comment: @Tarek , yeah that's true, this is just for simple scenarios, or we can say a quick fix. May be for someone who don't know how to work with combine.

Comment: Yea I thought of leaving this comment in case someone gets stuck trying to get it to work with protocols. But thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

The solution can be further simplified. Just use a Void publisher in your model. E.g.:

```
class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    private(set) var actionExecuted = PassthroughSubject<Void,Never>()

    func execute() {
        actionExecuted.send()
    }
}

class MyView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @StateObject var model = MyModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hi")
        .onReceive(model.actionExecuted) {
            dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have **a single** method that can be executed either from the `View` or from the `ViewModel`, you can achieve it like this (even simpler without Combine):

`View`:

```
class MyView: View {

    // MARK: - Private Properties

    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: ViewModel

    // MARK: - Init

    init(viewModel: ViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    // MARK: - Body

    var body: some View {
        Text("My View")
            .onChange(of: viewModel.shouldDismiss) { dismiss() }
    }
}
```

`ViewModel`:

```
extension MyView {

    // MARK: - ViewModel

    @MainActor class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

        // MARK: - Internal Properties

        @Published var shouldDismiss: Bool = false

        // MARK: - Internal Methods

        func dismiss() {
            shouldDismiss = true

            // Track analytics event, etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

- If you want to dismiss the view from `ViewModel`, you can call `dismiss()` method directly.
- If you want to dismiss the view from the `View` itself, you can do so by calling `viewModel.dismiss()` in the same way.

*P.S.
This is not the ideal option, as MVVM doesn't always perfectly fit into SwiftUI. However, if you want to have one method, for example, to close the screen and also send analytics events or anything else, my example above will allow you to achieve this result.*