# Pop Navigation view from ViewModel

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm using swiftUI and combine, I'have some business logic in my VM. Some results have to pop my view in navigation view stack.

I'v used this one in some views to simulate backbutton event :

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
```

I tried it in view model but it doesn't work. Any ideas ?

Comment: No ideas until you show code that don't work ))

Comment: the code showed does't work in view model.

Comment: This code needs to be in your view. Your view model doesn't have a `presentationMode`

Comment: Agree with that, that why I'm looking to do something similar in my VM.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59103163/dismiss-view-from-view-model-modal-page/59103792) that I answered previously.

You can achieve this by implementing your custom `Publisher` which will use `.send()` method to allow you to send specific values to the subscriber (in this case, your `View`). You will use `onReceive(_:perform:)` method defined on the `View` protocol of **SwiftUI** to subscribe to the output stream of the custom `Publisher` you defined. Inside the `perform` action closure where you will have the access to the latest emitted value of your publisher, you will do the actual dismissal of your `View`.

Enough of the theory, you can look at the code, should not be very hard to follow, below:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var viewDismissalModePublisher = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
    private var shouldPopView = false {
        didSet {
            viewDismissalModePublisher.send(shouldPopView)
        }
    }

    func performBusinessLogic() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.shouldPopView = true
        }
    }
}
```

And the views are:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, World!")
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("Detail")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Home"))
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail")
        .navigationBarTitle("Detail", displayMode: .inline)
        .onAppear {
            self.viewModel.performBusinessLogic()
        }
        .onReceive(viewModel.viewDismissalModePublisher) { shouldPop in
            if shouldPop {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've also updated the old question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59103792/3687801).

Comment: Thanks. I need to spend more hours on combine framework.